# Probability of rolling a 2 before a 6 and a 1 in that order

Tags: probability

> I am rolling a fair die. What is the probability that the first time I see a $2$ is before the first time I see a $6$ , and the first time I see a $6$ is before the first time I see a $1$ ?

So I thought about doing it with an infinite sum: 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\frac{4}{6}\frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{6}\big(\frac{4}{6}\big)^2\frac{1}{6} + \dots
\end{align}
where the first term is rolling a $2$ and then rolling a $6$ , the second term is rolling a $2$ , rolling anything but a $1$ or $6$ and then rolling a $6$ , etc. but I don't believe this is correct.

Comment: This is very similar to your earlier question.  Your idea there was already a very good one.  Recognize that if we ignore all rolls other than $1,2,6$ and if we only keep track of the first time that each are seen, we have the $3!=6$ different possible permutations of 1-2-6 and that these are equally likely to occur.  2-6-1 is the only one of the six equally likely possible permutations corresponding to the event you are interested in, so it occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: At a glance it does not appear correct, no.  It looks like the probability you calculated is the probability that a $2$ occurs on the first roll, followed by an undetermined number of rolls (possibly zero) in which neither a $6$ nor a $1$ occur, followed by a $6$.  In the way you worded the question however, a $2$ is allowed to occur *any* time before the first six and is not required to be the first roll.

Comment: @JMoravitz your solution is nice!

Comment: @JMoravitz Ah thanks I deleted that question earlier because I ended up using my idea to solve it shortly after I posted it and I was trying to see if there was another way to do it with summations but it appears that the other method is the most elegant. This was to get an idea of how to do it using summations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your roll will look like this:

$\qquad (\text{1})$: $k$ rolls, each roll being one of $3,4,5$
$\qquad (\text{2})$: a $2$
$\qquad (\text{3})$: $m$ rolls, each roll being one of $2,3,4,5$
$\qquad (\text{4})$: a $6$
$\qquad (\text{5})$: $n$ rolls, each roll being one of $2,3,4,5,6$
$\qquad (\text{6})$: a $1$

For each $k$, $(1)$ has probability $(1/2)^k$.
For each $m$, $(3)$ has probability $(2/3)^m$.
For each $n$, $(5)$ has probability $(5/6)^n$.
Steps $(2)$, $(4)$ and $(6)$ each have probability $1/6$.

All in all, that gives you

\begin{align}
\left[\sum_{k\geq 0} {\left(\frac12\right)}^k\right]
\cdot \frac16\cdot
\left[\sum_{m\geq 0} {\left(\frac23\right)}^m\right]
\cdot \frac16\cdot
\left[\sum_{n\geq 0} {\left(\frac56\right)}^n\right]
\cdot \frac16
&=
\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac12\right)\,\left(1-\frac23\right)\,\left(1-\frac56\right)\,6^3}
\\&=
\frac{1}{\frac12\cdot\frac13\cdot\frac16\cdot 6^3}
\\&=
\frac16
\end{align}

Comment: That said, JMoravitz's comment on the question itself leads to a decidedly more elegant solution. :)